# Why doesn't this template class work inside another class?

Tags: c++, templates, static-classes

I can do:

```
template <int n>
struct Buffer
{
    char buffer[n * 128];
};

template <int n>
Buffer<n> buffer; // When I instantiate this the compiler makes many different static variables


int main()
{
    buffer<sizeof(int)>;
    buffer<sizeof(char)>;
    buffer<sizeof(double)>;
    buffer<sizeof(std::string)>;
}
```

But for some reason it fails to compile when I want the buffer object inside a class as a static variable:

```
template <int n>
struct Buffer
{
    char buffer[n];
};

struct MyStaticClass
{
    template <int n>
    static inline Buffer<n> buffer;
};

int main()
{

    MyStaticClass::buffer < sizeof(int)>;
    //'public: static Buffer<4> MyStaticClass::buffer<4>': inline variable is undefined

}
```

I am on Visual 2019 Community 16.4.5
I have /std:c++latest flag on

Comment: Are you using C++17? If not, you need to define the members because `inline` does not work prior to C++17. [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/5MahWEoY9).

Comment: `inline static` is a C++17 extension

Comment: Works in C++17. But what do you want to do with the commented line?

Comment: @Quimby Yes I use C++17 features, I have the c++latest flag on. I can do this with ordinary variables, static inline int and other types, it's just this template example that's failing.

Comment: Code works fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zzGbbfcrs).  Can we get the compiler, version, compiler flags, and the complete error message?

Comment: Hmm, this may be a bug, I use static inline all the time because I don't like rewriting variables in cpp files. It's just choking on this template case.

Comment: Still, cannot reproduce that even with `/std:c++latest` on godbolt.

Comment: Based on the godbolt link by @Quimby, this code fails for msvc v19.26 and earlier - I guess an upgrade is in order.

Comment: Yep.  Looks like the OP needs to update MSVS

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Nice catch, did not try earlier builds.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker OK, thank you.